# I am getting the Compile error:- sub or function not defined in Excel!! Please note the References in tool tab is not active

Tags: excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    send email 
End Sub

Public Function sendmail() 
     On Error GoTo ende 

     esubject = "Systematic and Manually Created ASN" 
     sendto = "oo@hp.com" ccto = "rt@hp.com" 
     ebody = "Hello All" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please find the Systematically and Manually created ASN for the last month" & _
      vbCrLf & "With Regards" & vbCrLf & "Tarak" 

     newfilename = "C:\Stuff.XLS"

     Set apps = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
     Set itm = app.createitem(0)

     With itm 
         .Subject = esubject 
         .to = sendto 
         .cc = ccto 
         .body = ebody 
         .attachments.Add (newfilename) 
         .display 
         .Send 
     End With

     Set app = Nothing 
     Set itm = Nothing

ende: 

End Function
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting.  Please do not post the full question in the title! - a brief title is better, and add the details in the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Oops I misread your sub name.

You should add this to the top of your module, to help yourself in the future.

```
Option Explicit
```

This updated suggestion actually runs.

Your code:
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        send email 
    End Sub

Should read:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    sendmail 
End Sub
```

Note the change from send email to sendmail.

Additionally:

```
Set apps = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set itm = app.createitem(0)
```

Should read

```
Set apps = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set itm = apps.createitem(0)
```

Note the missing s. Without that s, the code will error right after with itm.

Edit 2:

Perhaps it's easier to show you what I mean. When you use option explicit, you must explicitly declare your variables. The pro is that you will not be able to use variables that you have not declared which will keep you from using app when you meant apps for example.

Here is corrected version of your script:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        sendmail
End Sub

Public Function sendmail()
     On Error GoTo ende
    Dim esubject As String, sendto As String, ccto As String, ebody As String, newfilename As String
    Dim apps As Object, itm As Object

     esubject = "Systematic and Manually Created ASN"
     sendto = "oo@hp.com"
     ccto = "rt@hp.com"
     ebody = "Hello All" & vbCrLf & _
     "Please find the Systematically and Manually created ASN for the last month" & _
      vbCrLf & "With Regards" & vbCrLf & "Tarak"

     newfilename = "C:\Stuff.XLS"

     Set apps = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set itm = apps.createitem(0)

     With itm
         .Subject = esubject
         .To = sendto
         .cc = ccto
         .body = ebody
         .attachments.Add (newfilename)
         .display
         .Send
     End With

     Set apps = Nothing
     Set itm = Nothing

ende:

End Function
```

Comment: I believe my recent suggestions will allow your code to run as expected.

Comment: I've attached a version of your code that compiles as the last code sampling in my response. (Edit 2) You should be able to just copy that and paste it over what you've been working on. But in the future, use option explicit and declare your variables.

Comment: Thanx man you are a life saver!! u r the best ..Super!! Very impressed!!